# Sometimes array.length only works after .push() (WHY?)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function vertexes() {};
vertexes.prototype = [];

vertexes.prototype.add = function (x, y, z) {
    this.push(new vertex(x, y, z));
    return this[this.length-1];
}
```

Vertexes is a collection that contain vertex objects. Vertex objects should be accessed as an array (vertexes[0] is a vertex). The code above works just fine.

```
function vertexes() {};
vertexes.prototype = [];

vertexes.prototype.add = function (x, y, z) {
    this[this.length] = new vertex(x, y, z);
    return this[this.length-1];
}
```

However, the code just above doesn't. When declaring this[this.length] it always declares this[0], and returns undefined. If vertexes.prototype is an array, why does array.length only works when i .push() an element to it?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the `[]` operator has special behavior for actual arrays. The objects you are creating are not arrays.

If you try to an extend an array using a prototype, you will basically have an ordinary object with an Array's methods and default property values. Assigning values to it with `[]` will just result in adding properties to it and will have no effect on its length.

Note that with some finagling it *is* possible to extend an array in such a way that assigning values to it with brackets updates the length. It basically involves instantiating actual arrays and appending your own methods to each new instance.

See that here:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-extending-javascript-arrays-while-keeping-native-bracket-notation-functionality.htm

Additional reading: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Comment: Hmm, so it defines the length 0, because that's the []'s length??? What does push do to add and update the length?? I had no idea, i just used push because it required no length!! Guess i was lucky

Comment: @RFiischer Yes to your first question. `myObj.push(something)` will carry out the array `push` operation on your object, which (I presume) involves setting `myObj[length]` to `something` and then incrementing `myObj.length` by 1. It does this even if you call it on a plain object: `var o = {}; Array.prototype.push.call(o, 10); console.log(o);`